# preloading a library to a vagrant VM

Tags: linux, memory-management, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualization

I regularly use Vagrant with the libvirt provider to setup and run qemu+kvm virtual machines on Linux. Recently, I tried to use the [libhugetlbfs library](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO) to back the guest physical memory with hugepages (see my remark at the end*).

Normally, the library should be pre-loaded with the LD_PRELOAD environment variable:

```
>> LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so ... <my app>
```

Following this logic I tried:

```
>> LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so ... vagrant up
```

but noticed that it doesn't work as expected. The environment variable is not passed to the underlying guest machine, which I identify as "qemu-system-x86" in the process list (given by ps).

What I discovered is:

- It seems like "vagrant up" isn't the parent process of the guest machine. The parent process of "qemu-system-x86" is init, so I guess some daemon created it? I just don't understand how vagrant works...
- The user who creates the "qemu-system-x86" process is libvirt-qemu. For some reason I couldn't "sudo su" to this user...

Is there any method that I can define the LD_PRELOAD variable to the guest machine **from the outside**? Or perhaps some hack to inject an environment variable to an already running process?

* I know that libvirt-based virtualization employs two-dimensional page tables. I'm interested in changing the memory allocation at the host level, so I need to apply libhugetlbfs from the **"outside"**. Preloading libhugetlbfs for an application running inside the guest is no problem at all.